# Terminal match-anything pattern rule, multiple prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use (a slightly-modified version of) Paul Smith's [Advanced VPATH Method for Multi-Architecture Builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/#advanced) to build our app in different subdirectories, with different compiler flags for each one, based on environment variables passed to `make` on the command line.

The following `Makefile` is the simplified example of what we're doing:

- If the user calls `make debug=1`, the `output` target will be built into the `_debug` subdirectory with specific compiler flags
- If the user calls `make release=1`, the `output` target will be built into the `_release` subdirectory with specific compiler flags

---

```
RELEASEDIR := _release
DEBUGDIR := _debug

OBJDIRS :=
ifdef debug
    OBJDIRS += $(DEBUGDIR)
endif
ifdef release
    OBJDIRS += $(RELEASEDIR)
endif

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifndef OBJDIRS
    $(error Must define "debug" and/or "release" in the environment, e.g. "make debug=1")
endif
endif


#----- Begin section to determine what subdir(s) to change into
ifeq (,$(filter _%,$(notdir $(CURDIR))))
.SUFFIXES:

MAKETARGET = $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $@ -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile \
                 SRCDIR=$(CURDIR) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(OBJDIRS)
$(OBJDIRS):
        +@[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
        +@$(MAKETARGET)

Makefile : ;
%.mk :: ;

% :: $(OBJDIRS) ;

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf _*
else
#----- End subdir(s) section


VPATH = $(SRCDIR)

# do special things (e.g. set compiler flags) based on the subdirectory
CURRENT_SUBDIR := $(notdir $(CURDIR))

ifneq (,$(findstring $(RELEASEDIR),$(CURRENT_SUBDIR)))
    $(info ...set compiler flags specific to release build...)
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring $(DEBUGDIR),$(CURRENT_SUBDIR)))
    $(info ...set compiler flags specific to debug build...)
endif

output : prereq
        cp -f $< $@

# user can specify v=1 to turn verbosity up
$(v).SILENT:


#----- End the "subdirs" if-statement
endif
```

---

This works as I'm expecting if I only specify one of the two variables:

```
$ make debug=1 v=1
...set compiler flags specific to debug build...
cp -f /home/me/work/prereq output
```

and:

```
$ make release=1 v=1
...set compiler flags specific to release build...
cp -f /home/me/work/prereq output
```

And so the file `output` is created in both the `_debug` and the `_release` subdirectories.

The problem is that when I try to specify both variables, it only builds the target in the `_debug` subdirectory:

```
$ make clean
rm -rf _*
$ make debug=1 release=1 v=1
...set compiler flags specific to debug build...
cp -f /home/me/work/prereq output
```

---

I don't understand this behavior. `OBJDIRS` is equal to `"_debug _release"` in this case, and so my terminal match-anything rule (`% :: $(OBJDIRS) ;`) has *both* `_debug` and `_release` as prerequisites. Therefore, I'd expect GNU Make to check (and build) both of those prerequisites, but it's only building the first one (`_debug`).

Interestingly, if I explicitly specify the target to build on the command line, it builds both:

```
$ make clean
rm -rf _*
$ make debug=1 release=1 v=1 output
...set compiler flags specific to debug build...
cp -f /home/me/work/prereq output
...set compiler flags specific to release build...
cp -f /home/me/work/prereq output
```

---

I'm assuming that there's something I'm misunderstanding about how terminal [match-anything rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) work. I don't get why the behavior is different for when a target is explicitly specified versus when not.

I'm using GNU Make 3.82 in CentOS 7.

EDIT: I'm also seeing this behavior in GNU Make 4.2.1 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I have not completely analyzed your `makefile`, but the following stood out to me. Reading [9.2 Arguments to Specify the Goals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals):

> By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting
>   targets that start with a period). Therefore, makefiles are usually
>   written so that the first target is for compiling the entire program
>   or programs they describe. If the first rule in the makefile has
>   several targets, only the first target in the rule becomes the default
>   goal, not the whole list.

So executing `make debug=1 release=1 v=1`, without an explicit target mentioned, will result in only the first entry in your `$(OBJDIRS)` value to become the target, not the whole list. This will be `$(DEBUGDIR)`, and not `$(DEBUGDIR) $(RELEASEDIR)`. This seems to explain what you are observing.

An experiment with this snippet that mimics your situation demonstrates the behavior:

```
RELEASEDIR := _release
DEBUGDIR := _debug

OBJDIRS :=
ifdef debug
    OBJDIRS += $(DEBUGDIR)
endif
ifdef release
    OBJDIRS += $(RELEASEDIR)
endif


.PHONY: $(OBJDIRS)
$(OBJDIRS):
        @echo OBJDIRS = $(OBJDIRS), Target = $@

output: $(OBJDIRS)
        @echo Creating the output target
```

with the following results:

```
$ make debug=1
OBJDIRS = _debug, Target = _debug
$ make release=1
OBJDIRS = _release, Target = _release
$ make release=1 debug=1
OBJDIRS = _debug _release, Target = _debug
$ make release=1 debug=1 _release
OBJDIRS = _debug _release, Target = _release
$ make release=1 debug=1 output
OBJDIRS = _debug _release, Target = _debug
OBJDIRS = _debug _release, Target = _release
Creating the output target
```

Update: The above identifies the problem, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219071/1380680) is a solution (found by the OP)

Comment: If you haven't already, I definitely recommend reading that first link I gave about Paul's "Advanced VPATH Method". I learned about several Make features that I hadn't yet ever encountered

Comment: So what you're saying makes sense, and I think that's definitely my issue here. A couple things: 1) I can't use order-only prerequisites in this case, because each individual `OBJDIRS` target is what then calls the sub-`make` to go and build all of my sources in that directory...if it were instead an order-only prerequisite, it wouldn't get built again once the directory exists (right?); and ....(next comment)...

Comment: 2) to mitigate this, I tried moving the `% :: $(OBJDIRS) ;` target up above the `$(OBJDIRS)` target, to make it so it's the chosen target (and thus build both `OBJDIRS` targets, which are prerequisites of it), but it still only built `_debug`

Comment: @villapx Yes, I will read it, thanks for the pointer. I love his posts, a great teacher. Your remark about the target-only prerequisite is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Reinier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208507/5689220) is correct for what my problem was. My solution was check if `$(OBJDIRS)` contains more than one word, and if so, make words 2 through N (I just chose an arbitrarily high N of 100) prerequisites of word 1:

```
ifneq (1,$(words $(OBJDIRS)))
$(firstword $(OBJDIRS)): $(wordlist 2,100,$(OBJDIRS))
endif
```

So that section of the `Makefile` now looks like this:

```
.SUFFIXES:

MAKETARGET = $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $@ -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile \
                 SRCDIR=$(CURDIR) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(OBJDIRS)
$(OBJDIRS):
        +@[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
        +@$(MAKETARGET)

ifneq (1,$(words $(OBJDIRS)))
$(firstword $(OBJDIRS)): $(wordlist 2,100,$(OBJDIRS))
endif

Makefile : ;
%.mk :: ;

% :: $(OBJDIRS) ;

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf _*
```

Comment: That is a pretty creative solution. I would add a few lines of explanation for anybody who needs to maintain this, besides yourself :-)

Comment: Indeed. Definitely wrote a comment in our actual project

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized that there is *one* downside to this solution: since any `OBJDIR` beyond the first is a prerequisite of the first, some parallelism is lost when using `-j` for parallel builds, since `make` can't build the first `OBJDIR` until the latter ones are finished.

Comment: Found the better solution: make a target `all: $(OBJDIRS)` just above the `$(OBJDIRS)` target. That way, the `all` target gets picked when no targets are explicitly set on the command line, making _all_ of the `OBJDIRS` get built, and now they can all be built fully in parallel.